# Getting "Support for defaultProps in JSX" to work with higher-order components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hoc

TypeScript 3.0 introduced built-in [support for `defaultProps`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx).

The example given there works fine in my project:

```
export interface Props {
  name: string;
}
export class Greet extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    return <div>Hello {name.toUpperCase()}!</div>;
  }
  static defaultProps = { name: "world" };
}
// Type-checks! No type assertions needed!
let el = <Greet />;
```

However, now let's introduce a HOC:

```
export interface Props {
  name: string;
}
export class Greet extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { name } = this.props;
    return <div>Hello {name.toUpperCase()}!</div>;
  }
  static defaultProps = { name: "world" };
}

function withHOC<TProps>(Component: React.ComponentType<TProps>) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/function-component-definition
  return function ComponentHOC(props: TProps) {
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );
  };
}

const GreetHOC = withHOC(Greet);
// Doesn't type check!
let el = <GreetHOC />;
```

Here I see

```
Property 'name' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'.
```

How can I change `withHOC` to get it to work?

Demo app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ijf9bq?file=index.tsx

I found https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/issues/86#issuecomment-822911042, but [the example given there as a "working version"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljmADsYkpN0k4B1YGACwAqfJCCQAFHGADOcAN7k4cfiKQAuOFJhQmAc3IBfSpgCujDMAiM4Ad16DhogDwK4AYTg0WjACYzk6GAA6V1xIRiRmAQBPMCRHfwxg0MsImAkIaUdXAD44ADJuOyEVdOlsgBoXZCkIABsANyRvUpkAXjgAKQBlAA1AgBlgACMoFCgogFkURhQdJoBBGC1h4xYpLPK4AHkQXnjiIJDwFOYWrIq4AGskKIhMQv5i0Rbs7PJsgAoXI7DU9VdyABKOQuIgwYxQKxoWooKQyHiPBycTwRXyIA5JY7hZj7GoNJovEGKRREHysD7A%20TE4loSyaJRIlrqBH2EqSNpE6nE5SidT4fCVLlwQwualgiFWL5CxRZZLY%20Ci6WyQIq-jAKSBMDsuCwzq9AbDUbjKYzObeRbLIarJDrVybBKHOWpM45bL6OCKoXK1WM9nuz3EgD0byFgIo1MMikMIuhsJkACFVjBLB5qF40Q7Mb8cbIpMAAF5qDTLRg6Ta02rQdSabSl90FFlPcTs3JU4maFAwYBoODeJDsYy1NLa9ptoV5wt8kD4RXRyi0xj0pveRNLFPtWyIlQfVfJxhh%20d0%20AoODtCmn3KOXcpivQVoAIiI3nvcGD5AX9KGp7g59al%20X15QnUd6Pk0L5vkAA) doesn't seem to compile now.